# Precompilation of razor views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

Whats the best way to enable precompilation during build of razor-views / cshtml files for an umbraco project? I have tried the combination of https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorGenerator.Mvc/ and https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorGenerator.MsBuild/ but with no luck so far as it seems they do not support the nuget package reference style.